# Response.Redirect from inside IPN_Notified Event Handler

Tags: redirect, paypal, paypal-ipn, response.redirect

We are using **SpiceLogic's BuyNowButton** control with dedicated IPN_Notified event handler. Our payment processing logic requires buyer's redirection back to shopper site and we are interested to do it from **IPN_Notified** event handler after all verification there pass. We have noticed that **Server.Transfer** doesn't work there (gets suppressed) if you try to run it from inside event handler. **Response.Redirect** works as expected but raises non-braking exception "Thread was being aborted". Our question is: "Is there any known bad in redirecting buyer from IPN_Notified that way? Will it work in real PayPal environment as it works in our dev environment now?"

Answer (score 0):

IPN happens completely separate from the checkout experience.  A redirect will not work there because it's an entirely separate server session / communication.  It's not anything happening in the browser.

It sounds like you must be working with PayPal Standard, so if you want the user to be returned to a specific page on your site after checking out with PayPal you can look into setting up [Auto-Return](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside) in the PayPal account.  Even with that enabled, though, there is no guarantee the user will make it back to your site because they could simply close the browser before it redirects.

If you want to guarantee the user always gets back to your site you should move to using the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) instead of PayPal Standard.  It will require more coding skill and working with web services, but it will give you much more freedom to do exactly what you want to do with your user experience.

Comment: Thank you for prompt response Andrew. ExpressCheckout would be our next step. Currently we have already integration with PayPal done via SpiceLogic BuyNowButton control. We just upgraded it to a new version and wanted to do some improvements if and when possible. Do you have experience with PayPal_Returned event? Or more specifically speaking - Does Page_Load event fire when PayPal calls PayPal_Returned event handler or it is pure server-to-server call with no page load? We could not see it in our test site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the [SpiceLogic PayPal Control](https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control-4), the IPN_Notified event is completely a service type event, which is triggered by the PayPal IPN Notification service. The consumer of this event is a backend service from PayPal, not your customer. Your customer will never be redirected anywhere whatever you perform in your IPN_Notified event.

When PayPal IPN service calls your IPN URL, the IPN_Notified event is fired from your SpiceLogic PayPal control. But, PayPal does not care about that. PayPal simply calls that IPN Url and Post transaction data and then returns. So, if you issue a Response. Redirect, it will do nothing to PayPal IPN service. Response. Redirect is an instruction for the Browser, but PayPal IPN service is not a browser which will redirect.

If you want your user to redirect or convey a message, you need to use the PayPal_Returned event from the SpiceLogic PayPal Control.

In order to understand better the IPN and event workflow, please check these images.

[image]

[image]